# Kernel use earlycon for primary console

Tags: linux-kernel, console, uart

I'd like to continue to use my `earlycon` console for the rest of my system, not just early boot.  I'm working on a VM, and I'm using the 8250 UART as my primary I/O.  It has no practical speed limitations.

It's great when the system is booting.  The text comes in immediately without delay.  But, after the system boots, it switches over to regular console.  Then things get much slower.

```auto
[    0.518804] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    0.542227] printk: console [ttyS0] disabled
[    0.542800] 10000000.uart: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x10000000 (irq = 0, base_baud = 1048576) is a XR16850
[    0.543623] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    0.544302] printk: bootconsole [uart8250] disabled
```

I've tried setting both `earlycon` and `console` to no effect.

My current kernel command-line is: `ro earlycon=uart8250,mmio,0x10000000,1000000 console=ttyS0`

How can I configure Linux to use my boot console, `earlycon` or `console` as my primary UART for user I/O and things like inittab, etc.

Comment: `keep_bootconsole` is to keep early console going. It's all written in the documentation.

Comment: ??? Is that a troll? Or did you just misspell it? (there's no such thing as `keep_bootconsole`)

Comment: Ah, it's `keep_bootcon`... Doesn't seem to be doing what I want but I will continue to explore.

Comment: Darn, it looks like the early bootcon doesn't seem to be able to let init start into it.

Comment: "*use my boot console, earlycon or console as my primary UART for user I/O and things like inittab, etc.*" -- You probably can't do that unless you enhance the underlying serial driver. The typical serial console is only implemented as an output device to display messages. The input capability, i.e. reading, is left unimplemented.  E.G. see  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0/source/drivers/usb/serial/console.c#L257 and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0/source/drivers/tty/serial/8250/8250_core.c#L663 There are no read functions defined!

Comment: Buuumer.  And it looks like there's no way to configure any 8250 drivers to poll instead of running wide open :-/. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: They are actually polling (if you are talking about _kernel console_). The _user space console_ uses full featured driver.

Comment: All I know is when I printf(...) with bootcon, text SPEWS by at AMAZING SPEEDS.  If I printf with the not-bootcon, it is SLOWWWW

Comment: "*If I printf with the not-bootcon, it is SLOWWWW*" -- That makes no sense. Unless there's a lot of higher priority interrupts and DMAs, there's no reason for a slow UART. Are you claiming individual characters are slow, or the lines of messages? Instead of your qualitative guessing, measure the actual output timing of characters and lines with an oscilloscope or logic analyzer.